# order_by in Mongoid along find_by, NoMethodError - undefined method `order_by'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I have to retrieve the mongodb records in a sinatra app using Mongoid.
For this I am trying to order the records retrieved using the following query:

`@bin = Bin.find_by(bin_id: params[:bin_id]).order_by(:created_at.desc)`

But I am getting the NoMethodError,

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `order_by' for #<Bin:0x00000101d24d60>:
/Users/harshsingh/Documents/Codes/mogreet-requestbin/app.rb:79:in `block in <class:App>'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `call'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `block in compile!'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `[]'
...
```

I am not sure why the `order_by` is not working, I tried looking into the Mongoid docs but couldn't find anything helpful to me.

**Edit:**

Sorry I forgot to mention, I have an embedded document in the `Bin` document called `Callback`, with the relations `embeds_many :callbacks` and `embedded_in :bin, :inverse_of => :bins`, so I wanted to sort the `callbacks` documents within one particular `bin` based on `created_at`.

Comment: as suggested by @basia I solved this by adding the `order_by(created_at: "desc")` in the `for loop` in the view page, something like `<% for callback in @bin.callbacks.order_by(created_at: "desc") %>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after question edit, it looks like you're missing `callbacks` in this query

```
@callbacks = Bin.find_by(bin_id: params[:bin_id]).callbacks.order_by(created_at: "desc")
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had missed the callbacks in the query. I was doing so because I had to display the bin details along with the callbacks details in each bin. I solved this by adding the `order_by(created_at: "desc")` in the `for loop` in the view page, something like `<% for callback in @bin.callbacks.order_by(created_at: "desc") %>`

Answer (score 3):

[`find_by`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/Mongoid/Findable:find_by) returns a single document:

> **#find_by(attrs = {}) {|result| ... } ⇒ Document?**
>
> Find the first Document given the conditions.

and documents don't have `order_by` methods. If you want to find all the documents with that `bin_id` then use `where`:

```
@bins = Bin.where(bin_id: params[:bin_id]).order_by(:created_at.desc)
```

Note that I switched the instance variable to a plural name along the way since it now contains (possibly) several `Bin`s.

Comment: I have updated my question, sorry for not been clear earlier.